# How to differentiate $y = \frac{v^4 -10 v \sqrt(v) }{ 4v^2}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to figure out how to find the derivative of $y = \frac{v^4 -10 v \sqrt(v) }{ 4v^2}$.

The problem is I keep getting the wrong answer, and I think it's because I'm not sure what order to take when I apply the derivative rules to it.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: We can simply the function
$$y=\frac{1}{4}v^2 -\frac{5}{2}v^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: is $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{5}{2}v^
{-1/2} = \frac{-1}{2}v^{-3/2}$?

Comment: No it's $-\frac{5}{4} v^{-\frac{3}{2}} \frac{dv}{dx}$ by the chain rule.

Comment: But there's no $f \circ g$?

Comment: But you said you were differentiating with respect to $x$ meaning that as $v$ is a function of $x$ we must multiply the derivative of it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you just said.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dv} f(v) = f'(v)$ whereas $\frac{d}{dx} f(v) = f'(v) \frac{dv}{dx}$

Answer (score 0):

It is the quotient rule
$$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)'=\frac{a'b-ab'}{b^2}$$
$$a'=4v^3-10\sqrt{v}-10v\cdot \frac{1}{2}v^{-1/2}$$
$$b'=8v$$